# How to add captions to live stream using Expression Encoder 4 SDK

Tags: c#, video-streaming, expression-encoder-sdk

I have a live stream of video. I am using LiveJob from expression encoder to display and save this stream. Now I also want to add captions to it. How can I add captions using the script command ?

If you need any more information please comment. I am using Csharp wpf application.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes we have tried adding many things. Finally found a solution will add that as an answer.

Comment: Could you please add your solution, I have the same problem.